# Changing Wordpress URL.. Safe?

Tags: wordpress, seo

I have some links that I would like to change.. examples below:

I have:

site.com/**linktochange**/article-title-here

and i would like to change it to:

site.com/**link-to-change**/article-title-here

1. How do I add the dashes to these categories?
2. Is a 301 redirect needed? Will the articles below each category still work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress will allow you to change the permalink and take care of the rest, but you may lose some search engine hits.

More info here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

You could use mod_rewrite to redirect the old URLs to the new ones if you are hosting it yourself.

Comment: is there a way to apply this to all child links? It's a blog with over 8000 posts so wouldnt want to redirect every ingle one separately

Comment: Yes, mod_rewrite has pattern matching capabilities and wordpress will work on all URLs

Comment: is mod_rewrite added to the htaccess or somewhere else? any example of what i need to add?

Comment: Something like RewriteRule /linktochange/(.*) /link-to-change/$1

Answer (score 0):

You might not need to change your permalink for this. 
It might be easier to just edit the Category slug. (Dashboard > Posts > Category)

If your category were Open Source and its category slug is 'opensource', an article in that category would have the following URL structure with the permalink (/%category%/%postname%)

site.com/opensource/hello-world

You could change your Open Source category slug to: open-source and it would change the URL structure to:

site.com/open-source/hello-world

Hope this helps.

The “slug” is the URL-friendly version of the name. It is usually all lowercase and contains only letters, numbers, and hyphens.